# ip6tables will not accept -d destination but iptables will

Tags: iptables, ip, firewall, ipv6, ip6tables

I am trying to allow an IPv6 address connect to a certain IP on my server but not the others. The following is not working with ip6tables but it does work with just plain iptables. When I remove `-d xx.xx.xx.77` from the ip6tables command it will work however, that will allow this ip6 address to connect to any IP on the box which I don't want.

```
ip6tables -I INPUT -d xx.xx.xx.77 -i enp2s0f0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 2400:cb00::/32 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables v1.6.0: host/network `xx.xx.xx.77' not found
```

`man ip6tables` shows the following for `-d` and `-s`:

```
   [!] -s, --source address[/mask][,...]
          Source  specification.  Address  can  be  either a network name, a hostname, a network IP address (with /mask), or a plain IP address. Hostnames will be resolved once only, before the rule is submitted to the kernel.  Please note that
          specifying any name to be resolved with a remote query such as DNS is a really bad idea.  The mask can be either an ipv4 network mask (for iptables) or a plain number, specifying the number of 1's at the left side of the network mask.
          Thus, an iptables mask of 24 is equivalent to 255.255.255.0.  A "!" argument before the address specification inverts the sense of the address. The flag --src is an alias for this option.  Multiple addresses can be specified, but this
          will expand to multiple rules (when adding with -A), or will cause multiple rules to be deleted (with -D).

   [!] -d, --destination address[/mask][,...]
          Destination specification.  See the description of the -s (source) flag for a detailed description of the syntax.  The flag --dst is an alias for this option.
```

Comment: Doesn't `ip6tables` expect IPv6 addresses?

Comment: I assume so but I dont have an ip6 address on my system, only ip4. So does that mean that these source ip6 addresses can access any ip4 on my server?

Comment: IPv6 and IPv4 are _different protocols_. If you do not have an IPv6 address then IPv6-only hosts cannot talk to your server at all. However, usually all IPv6-enabled hosts have at least a local-link IPv6 address.

Comment: What if an IP6 address, someone on the internet wants to connect to my server which has only ip4 addresses. I guess I do not know enough about ipv6. Can someone with an ipv6 address connect to my server which has only ip4 addresses?

Comment: They cannot connect using their IPv6 address. They need to connect using an IPv4 address. (There is no such thing as an IP datagram which mixes an IPv6 source address with an IPv4 destination address. Both source and destination must be of the same kind.)

Comment: `ip addr` will give you your addresses. But you should not change firewalls if you have no idea of what it is a ipv4, ipv6 tcp, udp, ports, etc.

Comment: I know what the difference is, I just don't know about how they connect with IPv4. AlexP has explained it. Thank you Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPv6 can not connect to an IPv4. in ip6tables everything needs to be ipv6